# OpenVPN as a background process

Tags: raspbian, networking, ssh, linux, vpn

i would like to run the OpenVPN service in the background. I have a script like this, that basically starts the Netherlands VPN of privateinternetaccess.

vpn.sh

> sudo openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/privateinternetaccess/Netherlands.ovpn --script-security 2 --up /etc/openvpn/privateinternetaccess/up.sh

The up.sh switches the `bind-address-ipv4` value to the current vpn ip address that is obtained.

up.sh

> /etc/init.d/transmission-daemon stop
>   sed s/IP_ADDRESS/$4/ /etc/transmission-daemon/settings_template.json > /etc/transmission-daemon/settings.json
>   /etc/init.d/transmission-daemon start

My problem is, i do run this bash script over ssh, and if i exit the ssh the OpenVPN process will stop.

Is there any way to run this in the background? I checked the manual i tried it with an extra `--daemon` flag, but after that it didn't give any feedback, and i didn't connected to vpn because `curl ifconfig.me/ip` returns my ip.

Comment: Have you tried something like this on another Linux system (Ubuntu, Debian, Mint, etc.) and had it work? If not, you will get better answers on [unix.se] as that is a question for Linux-centric issues. Raspberry Pi SE (this site) is for issues that only occur on the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Hello, actually my problem got solved already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a debian-way of running OpenVPN, which is a lot easier than trying with different scripts on your own.

When you install openvpn using the package manager (apt), like:

> sudo apt-get install openvpn

It will create a */etc/openvpn* and a */usr/share/doc/openvpn/examples/sample-config-files* directories that are relevant to this answer.

Browse the configuration examples in */usr/share/doc/openvpn/examples/sample-config-files* and pick one that you can alter to do whatever you want to do with OpenVPN. I assume you will use the *client.conf* file so that your RPi will connect to some OpenVPN server somewhere.

Copy that file into */etc/openvpn*, like this:

> sudo cp /usr/share/doc/openvpn/examples/sample-config-files/client.conf /etc/openvpn

Now go to */etc/openvpn* and edit the file to your configuration.

Everytime your RPi boots, init will run OpenVPN with all the configuration files in that */etc/openvpn* directory, if you don't act otherwise. So, it will automatically start that OpenVPN configuration *client.conf* that you dropped in there, in the background.

If you want to start/stop it manually, try:

> sudo service openvpn stop

or

> sudo service openvpn start

accordingly.

Remember that all the configuration files in */etc/openvpn* will be executed automatically at boot-time.

Comment: Thank you, its good to know configs under /etc/ starts after boot. I read through the config file but I have absolutely no idea what should I edit. I am an absolute noob, especially in the networking topic. All i know is i going to use my privateinternetaccess vpn and they have a openvpn.zip package that contains these certificates.